# Set allowing quick insert/deletion and random selection in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

What data structure could I use in C# to allow quick insertion/deletion as well as uniform random selection?  A List has slow deletion by element (since it needs to find the index of the element each time), while a HashSet does not seem to allow random selection of an element (without copying to a list.)

The data structure will be updated continuously, so insertion and deletion need to be online procedures.  It seems as if there should be a way to make insertion, deletion, and random selection all O(log n).

A binary search tree with arbitrary integer keys assigned to the objects would solve all of these problems, but I can't find the appropriate class in the C# standard library.  Is there a canonical way to solve this without writing a custom binary search tree?

Comment: What will your uniform random selection criteria be? If you can use key/value pairs, then a Dictionary might suit your purpose.

Comment: I basically just need to put all the objects in a hat, and pull out one at random (but keeping it in the hat.)  For purposes here, the objects have no structure; I can associate a unique ID with each object if necessary, but it's a meaningless choice

Comment: `(since it needs to find the index of the element each time),` No, that is not the main reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that this question is over 3 years old, but just for people who come across this page:

If you don't need to keep the items in the data set sorted, you can just use a `List<ItemType>`.

Insertion and random selection are O(1). You can do deletion in O(1) by just moving the last item to the position of the item you want to delete and removing it from the end.

Code:

```
using System; // For the Random
using System.Collections.Generic; // The List

// List:
List<ItemType> list = new List<ItemType>();

// Add x:
ItemType x = ...; // The item to insert into the list
list.Add( x );

// Random selection
Random r = ...; // Probably get this from somewhere else
int index = r.Next( list.Count );
ItemType y = list[index];

// Remove item at index
list[index] = list[list.Count - 1]; // Copy last item to index
list.RemoveAt( list.Count - 1 ); // Remove from end of list
```

**EDIT:** Of course, to remove an element from the `List<ItemType>` you'll need to know its index. If you want to remove a random element, you can use a random index (as done in the example above). If you want to remove a given item, you can keep a `Dictionary<ItemType,int>` which maps the items to their indices. Adding, removing and updating these indices can all be done in O(1) (amortized).

Together this results in a complexity of O(1) (amortized) for all operations.

Comment: Are you sure insertion (where? in the middle?) is O(1)?

Comment: @GáborBakos Just at the end of the `List` using the `Add` method. Of course, if it's got to grow the array, it takes longer. But that still results in O(1) amortized and if you take a proper initial capacity it won't have to grow the array very often (if at all).

Comment: This comes with an additional caveat for the use case I believe I had years ago: if you have an element but not its index (and all elements are unique), then removal is O(n).  Thus you also need to maintain an element -> index mapping, perhaps with a HashMap if the elements are hashable.

Comment: @CoreyStaten That's exactly what it says in my edit. A Dictionary in C# is a hash map.

Comment: Woops, somehow I missed your edit when reading!

Answer (score 2):

There is already a BST in the C# BCL, it's called a `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, if you don't want Key Value Pairs, but instead want single items, you can use the `SortedSet<T>` (SortedSet is in .NET 4.0).

It sounds like from your example you'd want a `SortedDictionary<int, WhateverValueType>`.  Though I'm not sure exactly what you are after when you say "uniform random selection".

Of course, the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is O(1) which is much faster.  So unless you have a need for sorted order of the keys, I'd use that.

**UPDATE**: From the sounds of your needs, you're going to have a catch-22 on efficiency.  To be able to jump into a random contiguous index in the data structure, how often will you be inserting/deleting?  If not often, you could use an array and just Sort() after (O(n log n)), or always insert/delete in order (O(n)).

Or, you could wrap a `Dictionary<int, YourType>` and keep a parallel `List<int>` and update it after every Add/Delete:

```
_dictionary.Add(newIndex, newValue);
_indexes.Add(newIndex);
```

And then just access a random index from the list on lookups.  The nice thing is that in this method really the Add() will be ~ O(1) (unless List resizes, but you can set an initial capacity to avoid some of that) but you would incurr a O(n) cost on removes.

I'm afraid the problem is you'll either sacrifice times on the lookups, or on the deletes/inserts.  The problem is all the best access-time containers are non-contiguous.  With the dual `List<int>/Dictionary<int, YourValue>` combo, though, you'd have a pretty good mix.

**UPDATE 2**: It sounds like from our continued discussion that if that absolute performance is your requirement you may have better luck rolling your own.  Was fun to think about though, I'll update if I think of anything else.

Comment: I don't need the sorted order; the elements naturally have no "key", they're just data objects.  By uniform random selection, I mean if there are N objects in the container, I want to randomly select with probability 1/N that I'll get any given object.  To randomly select from a dictionary, I think I need to turn the KeyCollection() into a list and do something like keys[random.Next(0, keys.Count())]; but either turning the KeyCollection into a list or creating the KeyCollection in the first place will be O(n), won't it?

Comment: @Corey: Then you could use Dictionary<int, YourType> and choose a random number using Random class and lookup the value.  The main problem will be if you remove an item, would that number no longer be eligible for random selection?  Just trying to find out if the indexes will remain constant but the content will change?

Comment: @Corey: I added some updates.  There's not a base collection that can do that, i think no matter what you'll pay a penalty somewhere in maintaining a list of "active" items so you can go to a random location quickly, my latter suggestion would give you great behavior on lookups and adds, and less on removes, but overall would be good.  Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  The access will usually be 1-3 random accesses, then one insert or delete (Around 50% chance of each), so all three operations happen with the same order of magnitude.  Although SortedDictionary uses a BST behind the scenes, selecting randomly from a BST depends on having the BST structure available (either as a flat array as in a heap, or by being able to follow the nodes.)  So none of these do what a custom BST could do in terms of performance (which may be the answer to my question!)

Comment: @Correy: Very true...  sorry couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 2):

Binary search trees and derived structures, like `SortedDictionary` or `SortedSet`, operate by *comparing* keys.

Your objects are not comparable by itself, but they offer object identity and a hash value. Therefore, a `HashSet` is the right data structure. Note: A `Dictionary<int,YourType>` is not appropriate because removal becomes a linear search (O(n)), and doesn't solve the random problem after removals.

- Insert is O(1)
- Remove is O(1)
- RandomElement is O(n). It can easily be implemented, e.g.

  ```
  set.ElementAt(random.Next(set.Count))
  ```

  No copying to an intermediate list is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the set.ElementAt example; that is useful and saves some time.  However I know that if I use a custom binary search tree based on a random unique ID associated to each object, I can do all three operations in O(log n).  Performance is a big issue for this application, and as my comments below indicate all three operations are used in roughly equal proportions so the O(n) there would dominate.  Seems like there just isn't a standard .NET component for this type of functionality.

Comment: You are right. When you add a random unique id to your objects _and_ use a BST all operations become O(log n). Unfortunately, the BCL does not contain a useful public implementation - `SortedDictionary` _is_ a BST, but exposes no useful API.